# SSRS default location for ReportServer.mdf

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to configure ssrs on a server and when I try to create the ReportServer and ReportServerTempDB I get the following error:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Directory lookup for the file "D:\microsoft sql server\data\ReportServer.mdf" failed with the operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).

I have tried changing the default data directory by right-clicking on the server in Object explorer then Properties>Database Settings then setting the paths here but I still get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't have permissions to write to the folder you are specifying.

You need to make sure that the service account SQL Server is running under has write permissions on the folder path you are trying to write to.

**Edit:**

Use the following steps:

```
//SqlExpress
1.Click the Windows Start button, and then click Run. The Run dialog box appears.
2.Type Services.msc into the Open field, and then click OK. The Services
  panel appears:
3.Right-click the SQL Server (SqlEx[ress) service, and then click Properties from          the     shortcut menu. The SQL Server (SqlExpress) Properties (Local   Computer) dialog box appears:
4.On the Log On tab, select Local System account for the Log on as option.
5.Press Apply and then press OK on the dialog box that appears.
6.Click on the General tab and then press Stop the stop the service, and Start to         restart the SqlExpress service.
7.Press OK and close the services Console.
8.Launch SqlExpress and attempt to now restore the database.
```

Comment: The folder doesn't exist. There is no D: drive to speak of. I want to change the default location anyway.

Comment: You may get this error if you are pointing to non-existent directory. You can view and change this setting in SQL Server Management Studio.  Right-click the server, choose Properties and then choose the Database Settings page (Use existing folder).

Comment: Can you try to create by restarting SQL Service?

Comment: Thanks  abhijeetdhumal I restarted then it worked! :-)

Comment: Great to hear that. If this has worked for you, you can upvote the answer and mark it accepted.